# Adding a wildcard (*) to a PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, wildcard

I'm trying to update the `"$searchValue"` below to include a wildcard  before & after so if the string in `"$searchValue"` is found anywhere in the `$label` it will work. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
        foreach($json as $key=>$value){

            foreach($value as $item)
            {
                if($item->$label == "$searchValue")
                {
                    echo $item->title.'<br>';
                }
            }    
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you're actually trying to do is determine whether the search value appears as a substring of the values you're checking against, which you can do with [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($json as $key=>$value){

        foreach($value as $item)
        {
            if(strpos($item->$label, $searchValue) !== false) 
            {
                echo $item->title.'<br>';
            }
        }    
    }
```